# How can I add a JOIN and a GROUP BY with an unnested array to a Django ORM query?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, group-by

In an existing system, I'm often using the Django `values()` followed by `annotate()` pattern to effect an SQL `GROUP BY`.

However, for a new feature, I need to join the whole query with an additional array, and I need to `GROUP BY` the elements of that additional array. In PostgreSQL, it looks something like this (greatly simplified):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM some_table
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C']) AS name) tag ON some_table.t LIKE tag.name || '%'
GROUP BY (some_table.some_column, tag.name);
```

I would like to stay in ORM-land, because the query goes through a whole sequence of follow-up transformations which I would like to keep consistent.

Is there a way in which I can 1) join with the runtime-defined (different for every query) array and 2) add it to the existing `GROUP BY` sequence?

Comment: Django ORM isn't powerful enough to handle this, to stay in the sweet ORM land I ended up injecting extra join conditions to the raw sql string at the very end after ORM is done with generating sql and before it is executed. So your options are: switch ORM (sqlalchemy), switch to raw sql, or what I did, nasty stuff either way.

Comment: modifying the sql at the end was my dirty-only-if-there's-no-other-way backup solution. :) I was hoping there was some neat ORM trick that I did not know about. I'm currently evaluating extending the ORM itself to do what I need to do.